# How to return 2 indexes of a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm writing this program to find 2 numbers in a vector (the vector isn't sorted), so that its sum equal to the target sum. This is my program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<size_t> find_numbers(const vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); // Sort the vector

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        if (binary_search(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target - nums[i]))
            return {i, ?}; // How to return the second number's position?

    return {};
}
```

If I add another loop to find the second number's position, the running time will be O(n^2), I want my program to run in O(nlogn). How can I return the second number's position?

Comment: `sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());` won't work because `nums` is `const`. Your function fundamentally needs to be able to change `nums` otherwise the returned range of indices is meaningless.

Comment: You are looking for `lower_bound`. `binary_search` only tells you whether or not the element exists, while `lower_bound` actually reports where it is.

Comment: I suggest you study more about [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) for handling pair of values.

Comment: How can you guys remember every built-in functions in C++?

Comment: @abcd Years of experience. And access to good references and search engines. :)

Comment: Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2olsGf6JIkU). It a gives a very nice overview that makes it much easier to remember.

Comment: You can either create struct of two variable or pass out (reference) parameters to function. And set value of those parameters in function

Comment: On another note, since `nums` is a references to a *constant* vector, you can't modify it (with e.g. `std::sort`). If you want to sort it, pass the vector by value so you have a copy you can freely modify.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) simply returns a `bool` indicating whether the element you're looking for exists. There is no information returned about the location of this element.

Instead, the appropriate algorithm would be [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) which does a binary search, and returns the location of where the element you're looking for should be, if it exists. So you could implement it like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
{
   auto it = std::lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target - nums[i]);
   if (it != nums.end() && *it == target - nums[i])
     return {i, std::distance(nums.begin(), it};
}
```

Also, the return type of your function is `vector<int>` which will work, but since you are always returning exactly 2 values, I suggest using `std::pair<int, int>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in an O(n) time complexity by holding an `unordered_map` from the difference from the target number to the index:

```
vector<size_t> find_numbers(const vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    unordered_map<int, int> map;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) 
    {
        int needed = target - nums[i];
        if (map.contains(needed)) 
        {
            return {map[needed], i};
        }
        else
        {
            map[needed] = i;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux arg, how embarrassing - forgot the `else` branch. Mea culpa. Edited.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `unordered_map.contains` on average, has a constant time complexity (see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains)

Comment: @Mureinik Oops, thought it was `std::map`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the text I had before the code was indeed confusing. I edited it to make it clearer I meant an `unordered_map`.